# Efficiently get a collection of all users following a list in SP2013 using CSOM or SSOM?

Tags: 2013, user, splist, following

Does anyone know if there is a way to leverage the `SocialFollowingManager()` class or the `SPList()` class to efficiently get a collection of all of the users that follow a specific List?

I thought about trying `SPList().GetItems()`, but I'm not getting the users who follow the list, just the list items.

The only way I can think to do this is to iterate through the entire userbase, create a `SocialFollowingManager()` for each user, and then leverage the `SocialFollowingManager().IsFollowed(SPSocialActor targetList)` method to see if that individual user is following the list.

I can't imagine that there doesn't exist a more efficient way to do this... has anyone had experience with this before?

Comment: This is really more of an idea than an answer, so I'll just leave this here...I suspect you might need to loop through all users to get what you're looking for.  You might consider writing a timer job (assuming on-prem) that runs overnight, and dumping your results to a list or some other data store. How many users do you have, by the way?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Derek... I thought about that solution as well, but sadly, I have 5000+ users, and don't know if SharePoint can handle that volume with any efficiency.

Comment: by follow do you mean people who get alerts from this list?

Comment: In addition to @Gwny - there is no definition for a list in the [SPSocialActorTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialactortypes.aspx) enumeration, so you can't follow a list.

Comment: but you Can set an alert to a list, that's what I meant

Answer (score -1):

Check this link out -
http://sundarnarasiman.net/?p=186

It might not be same, but can help in getting the logic.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. Add relevant parts from the link to your post to make it helpful even if the link breaks

Comment: Sure Robert, will take care of that in future.

Comment: Please do it for this post as well so it doesn't get deleted